# Fundamental domain of a Fuchsian group is non-compact if the group contains parabolic element

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{H}^2$. Why is the fundamental domain non-compact if $\Gamma$ contains a parabolic element? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The conjugacy class of the parabolic element corresponds to a cusp in the quotient manifold. when you "unfold" the surface in the universal cover, the cusp corresponds to a set of ideal vertices of your fundamental region (i.e. vertices on the boundary of the hyperbolic disc). Hope this helps.